# vue.js - Data doesn't show in console.log but renders fine in template

Tags: vue.js, render, console.log

I have a Vue template in which I make async/await calls to get all sessions data, this data does not have to be rendered, but sent to another component in the form of an array, and the other component will get that info and produce some graphs. As a test, I added the array `sessionSelected` to the html template to see if it loads correctly and works just fine (This data change is triggered by a select component when selecting a `program`).

The behavior that I'm confused with however can be seen in the listSessions() method below, where I have console.log(val) that is inside a map for the `sessionSelected` array iteration;

When I check the console, the object that is being returned there is blank the first time I choose an option from the select component (a program), but when I pick  another option, let's say `program 6` it loads the previous sessions in the console.log(val), even though the same data object, when iterated through in the template, is displaying all the sessions correctly . (It's kinda like it always go, one "tick" behind)

A possible hint, if it helps, I added an `@click` to a `<p>` element below the select's components, so when the program is chosen, say  `program 2`, and then I click to that `<p>` tag, the console.log does show correctly from the "listSessions" method.

I need to be able to have the sessionSelected array object synced, in such a way so that I'm sure that when I select a program, in the html template, the method will retrieve the right array (of sessions) like shows rendered in template.

```
<template>
<v-container>
    <v-layout>
        <v-flex lg4 sm12 xs12>
                <GPSelect @input="listTreatments" v-model="patientSelected" :items="tvPatients" label="Patients" />
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex lg4 sm12 xs12>
                <GPSelect @input="listPrograms" v-model="treatmentSelected" :items="treatments" label="Treatments" :disabled="treatments === undefined || treatments.length === 0" />
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex lg4 sm12 xs12>
                <GPSelect @input="listSessions" v-model="programSelected" :items="programs" label="Programs" :disabled="programs === undefined || programs.length === 0" />

            <p @click="listSessions">Session selected {{sessionSelected}}</p>
            <p>ProgramSelected {{programSelected}}</p>

        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

    <BarChart :label="label" :data="dataSet" :labels="labels" />

</v-container>
</template>

<script>

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            tvPatients: [],
            patientSelected: "",
            treatments: [],
            programs: [],
            sessions: [],
            treatmentSelected: "",
            programSelected: "",
            sessionSelected: [],
            dataSet: [],
            ...       
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.listPatients();
    },

    methods: {

        async listSessions() {

            await this.getSessions();
            this.updateData();

            this.sessionSelected.map(async (val) => {
                console.log( val)
            })

            this.sessionSelected.length = 0;
            this.sessions.length = 0;

        },

        async getSessions() {

            if (this.patientSelected) {

                const response = await SessionService.getSessions(null, "meta");
                if (response.data) {
                    return response.data.map(async (val, index) => {
                        if (val.program_id === this.programSelected) {
                            if (this.sessions != undefined) {

                                this.sessions.push(await SessionService.getSession(val._id, "meta"));
                                this.sessionSelected.push(await SessionService.getSession(val._id, "meta"));

                            }

                        }
                    })
                }

            }
        },
        async listPrograms() {

            this.programs = await this.getPrograms();
        },
        async getPrograms() {

            let response = await PatientService.getPatient(this.patientSelected, "tv");
            if (this.patientSelected) {

                const params = {
                    "treatment-id": response.data.documents[0].document.active_treatment_id
                };

                const programResponse = await ProgramService.getPrograms(params);

                return await programResponse.data.map((val, index) => {
                    return {
                        name: `Program ${(index + 1) } ${response.data.documents[0].document.first_name}`,
                        value: val._id
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }

}
</script>
```

I expect that the console.log(val) inside the map of the this.sessionSelected shows the same data displayed in the template, without having to use the `<p>` tag with the @click event as a hack, basically, that when a program gets selected from the select component, loads the associated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite difficult to follow with so much `async`/`await` going on. A bit of refactoring to deal with the pyramid of doom wouldn't hurt.

This line catches my eye:

```js
return response.data.map(async (val, index) => {
```

This will be returning an array of unresolved promises. The surrounding function, `getSessions`, is `async` so it will wrap the return value in a further promise.

The line `await this.getSessions();` will wait for that promise to resolve. Unfortunately it'll resolve immediately to the array of promises, without waiting for the individual promises to resolve. This is why the logging appears to be one step behind, as the inner promises haven't finished yet.

I think what you need is to add `Promise.all`, such that the outer promise waits for the array of promises.

```js
return Promise.all(response.data.map(async (val, index) => {
```